# sharepoint save a date to a date field

Tags: c#, sharepoint

How can you save a date in sharepoint programatically?

I have a list with a date field and want to save a date into that field and a regular 
DateTime field isnt working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to save a standard .NET DateTime object into a SPFieldDateTime, like so:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://YOUR URL"))
{
  using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()) 
  {
    SPList list = web.Lists["news"];

    SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

    item["Title"] = "Test";
    item["Expires"] = dt;

    item.Update();
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 because this was top 4 results when I searched in Bing. Thanks for quick help!

Comment: @Magnus : what if I want to update the date field with null value?

Answer (score 2):

you need to convert the date to iso format

```
myListItem["nameofmydatetimefield"] = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(mydatetimeobject);
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific about _why_ one would need to do this?